# Azure: keep same IP when shutting down?

Tags: azure

I'm signing up for a service that needs to verify my IP. I'm using an azure remote server and I'd like to keep using the service long-term.

The problem is that if I want to make changes on the server and later need to reboot or re-size the vm I will lose my IP and get a new one.

Is there away around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to this [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/).

Here is what it it looks on the new Azure dashboard *(too big to fit in one picture, second picture is same page but to the right of the first)*:

[image]

[image]